# Caret position is way off in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

Chrome (and maybe other browsers) position the caret in a strange way within a contenteditable div.

Please consider the following snippet:

```
<div contenteditable="true" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black; overflow: auto;">
    <p>
        <span contenteditable="false" style="width: 75%; height: 80px; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid red;">&nbsp;</span>.
    </p>
</div>
```

Also available in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/am5e4fhw/).

If you click on the right-side of the period next to the red span and press backspace to delete the period, the caret suddenly shifts to the extreme right of the paragraph. I would expect the caret to be positioned where the period used to be, next to the red span.

Why is it not positioned the way I expect, and is there a way to get the behavior I'm looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This strange behavior is happening because of the `p` tag, the cause is possibly some conflict between widths, you can edit the css of the tag, instead of using `display:block`(default), use `display:inline`.

I created this fiddle: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mathiasfcx/1n9nwtwe/), with `display:inline`, was the closest I could get from the `display:block`.

I tried the `align` attribute but I did not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly confident that it's the span causing it, because the moment you remove it or even `display: none` it, the problem goes away. I got really curious about this myself and did some searching, this person seems to have the same problem as you.

[Why Is My Contenteditable Cursor Jumping to the End in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786048/why-is-my-contenteditable-cursor-jumping-to-the-end-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Non-breaking spaces are just what they sound like — spaces where a line break will not occur. You should not use them to add space between words, sentences, or elements. Especially not elements.

Remove & nbsp; (with space or will actually make space :D) and everything's good.