# Flask-SocketIO div[contenteditable] multi edit sets the textbox cursor to start of the box

Tags: javascript, flask, socket.io

I'm an intermediate python developer, and I'm working on a practice project for a course, and I'm building a document app (kinda like google docs), and I'm trying to use Flask-SocketIO to add the ability to have multiple people edit the document as once. A pretty major problem I'm having with this process is whenever I type and emit the new text to the Server, and back to the Clients, every cursor in the documents gets reset to the start. How can I save the cursor position when the client get the new HTML?

```html
<div class="write-text" contenteditable="true">{{ 
    firstdocument.content | safe }}</div>
```

```
socket.on("textchanger", (msg) => {
    document.querySelector(".write-text").innerHTML = msg
})

$(document).ready(() => {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(mutation => {
            if (mutation.type == "characterData") {
                socket.emit('changetext', {text: document.querySelector(".write-text").innerHTML, room: "{{ firstdocument.id }}"})
            }
        })
    })
    observer.observe(document.querySelector(".write-text"), {attributes: true, characterData: true, subtree: true})
})
```

Comment: Hey Eitan, did a little research on my own.... apparently the contenteditable div has a few known issues.  Here's a post that details some of them and some workarounds. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786048/why-is-my-contenteditable-caret-jumping-to-the-end-in-chrome#:~:text=The%20problem%20is%20that%20your,be%20treated%20as%20inline%2Dblock%20.