# Mark some content as uneditable inside Quilljs container

Tags: javascript, html, quill

Is it possible to mark some content inside a quill container as unmodifiable? For example, suppose the starting container div is:

```
<div id="editor-container">
   <h1>This should not be editable.</h1>
</div>
```

And my javascript is simply:

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['image', 'code-block']
    ]
  },
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

I tried setting the contenteditable attribute on the heading to false but that didn't help. The heading was still editable in the resulting Quill editor. I also tried adding a "readonly" attribute but that didn't work either.

I have created the [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thirteenfishes/k11ea10h/) to show the readonly and contenteditable attempts.

Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This could be of use to you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615551/html-contenteditable-with-non-editable-islands

Seems like there might not be a good solution in the general case.

Answer (score -3):

this should be fine

```
basicEditor.editor.disable();
basicEditor.editor.enable();
```

Answer (score -3):

We can use existing function to disable editor [Quilljs Docs](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#enable)

```
quill.enable(false);
quill.disable();
```